# How can I bind a property to a relative controller path in Ember.JS

Tags: ember.js

I'm looking to bind a property on my object using a relative path to a controller.  In older versions of ember, controllers had absolute paths.  For a while, it also seemed like you could use getPath to get relative paths.  In RC5, I'm not sure how to bind to a relative path.

In this fiddle, I want to bind each item to a property called selectedId in the controller:

http://jsfiddle.net/skwd/eR9r8/

However, in the context of the controller, i'm not sure how to make that binding.  i don't have access (as far as i know) to an absolute or relative controller path.

```
App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    selectedId: 0,
    ...

    // items is an array of ember objects, each with a title and ID
    preparedItems: function() {
        var prepared = [];
        this.items.forEach(function(item) {
            // bind item.selectedId to this.selectedID?
        });
    }.property('items')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `isSelected` computed property is on the the `Item` object but you are changing `selectedId` in the `IndexController`'s `next` handler.

A quick way to fix this is to set the `isSelected` property on the item object itself in the `next` handler.

```
next: function() {
    var selectedId = this.get('selectedId');
    var prevItem = this.items[selectedId];
    if (prevItem) {
      prevItem.set('isSelected', false);   
    }

    var nextId = Math.min(this.get('selectedId') + 1, this.items.length - 1);
    this.set('selectedId', nextId);

    var nextItem = this.items[nextId];
    nextItem.set('isSelected', true);
}
```

Here's the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eR9r8/7/).

Having said that I would suggest reading up on the Ember [Getting Started Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started).

The problem you are facing, ie:- differentiating an item while looping over a collection, is actually solved in a better way using Ember's itemController. You do this by looping over the collection and specify an itemController in the `#each`. This requirement is addressed in Ember in a very idiomatic way, I'd suggest using that approach instead.

Edit: Fixed the jsfiddle link.

For relative bindings you can bind to any property of another controller/object with `Ember.bind`, or `Ember.Binding.from`. See the [api docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Binding.html) for `Ember.Binding`. Also see [this link](http://code418.com/blog/2012/03/26/advanced-emberjs-bindings/) for more advanced ember binding examples.

Comment: Thanks Darshan. This fiddle is actually a simpler example of a more complex thing I want to do.  So my focal question is not "how do i show an item in a list as selected" but instead, "how do I set up a relative binding?"  Do you have tips for the focal question at hand?

Comment: Also, your fiddle seems not to have been saved. You may want to save the fiddle and update your answer.

Comment: I've fixed the link and updated my answer. You probably want to use, Ember.bind.

Comment: Ember.bind looks good, though it has a restriction.  The paths must be relative to obj, or be absolute paths.  What if both properties are on different objects and you don't know the absolute path for either of them?

Comment: If you find unrelated objects needing to communicate like that, I would suggest using events instead. Eg:- an `addProduct` event would add to the cart list while also updating the total in another view, etc. So even if the different pieces are dependent it's well defined through the event as a contract.